# Cannot access to swagger UI using tomcat, spring boot and Rest

Tags: rest, spring-boot, http, swagger-ui

I am trying to add swagger ui documentation to my spring boot application.
Here the steps I did into my code:

Add dependencies to my POM.XML

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

then add swagger annotation to the swagger config as follow:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
       @Bean
        public Docket api() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.foo.samples.swaggersample"))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build();
        }
}
```

when executing this url: http://localhost:8080/my-app-name/swagger-ui.html
I got this result:

[image]

Your help will be more than welcome!

Comment: You should have an error or exception in your application logs from that 500. What is it?

Comment: Oui, le voilà:  Forwarding to error page from request [/api/swagger.html] due to exception [No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@4521efdb; line: 1, column: 0]]
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@4521efdb; line: 1, column: 0]
 at

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3838) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]at om.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3783) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]at

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2908) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7] at fr.eni.ewsa.rest.security.TokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication(TokenAuthenticationService.java:67) ~[classes/:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @ChrisSavory tu penses que c'est relié à une compatibilité avec ma version de maven et spring boot et swagger2?

Comment: What happens when you go to `/swagger-ui.html` instead of `/my-app-name/swagger-ui.html`?  Also, try this: `/v2/api-docs`

Comment: If I use the link without my-app-name, it will display a non found page! Error 404

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar issue (my error code is 404 not 500 like yours), until I added resource handler:

```
@Override
protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

Hope that helps